# Пятая часть - дробное количественное или порядковое числительное?

Tags: числительные

*В озере Байкал содержится пятая часть мирового запаса пресной воды.*

"Пятая" - дробное количественное или порядковое числительное? По смыслу содержания пропущено слово "одна" и тогда "одна пятая" - это дробное количественное числительное. Если задавать вопрос (часть (какая?) пятая), то это порядковое числительное.

Помогите понять, какое числительное?

Comment: Оксана, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Comment: ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ дробных числительных:  Дробные числительные представляют собой  с л о в о с о ч е т а н и е  количественных и порядковых числительных: количественное числительное – числитель дроби, порядковое  (в форме мн. числа)  – знаменатель дроби: пять шестых,. Дробные числа расшифровываются следующим образом: пять шестых – это пять шестых ДОЛЕЙ (ЧАСТЕЙ) единицы. Дробные числа  образуют количественные сочетания с существительными. Примеры: Горы покрывают ДВЕ ПЯТЫХ территории штата. Если числитель равен единице, то он может пропускаться: (одна) пятая часть запасов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В озере Байкал содержится **пятая часть** мирового запаса пресной воды.*

1. Было сказано: «Если задавать вопрос (часть (какая?) пятая), то это **порядковое** числительное».

Но дело в том, что вопрос к порядковым числительным надо задавать правильно: **который/какой по счету?**

Здесь к числительному нельзя задать вопрос «которая по счету», поэтому это не порядковое числительное.

2. А **какой вопрос** надо задавать к дробным числительным? С точки зрения грамматики это словосочетание. Можно ли  задать вопрос «какая часть?» и ответить "пятая часть"? Можно, но это будет вопрос только **к знаменателю дроби,** а не ко всему словосочетанию.

Дробные числа являются количественными, поэтому следует спросить **«сколько?»** Ответ: (одна) пятая часть.

Comment: Вот и мы с ученицей шестого класса рассуждали подобным образом и пришли к выводу, что числительное дробное. Однако, учитель в школе исправила морфологический разбор, указав, что это порядковое числительное. Каждый остался при своем мнении...

Comment: Думаю дело вот в чем. Надо различать синтаксический и морфологический разборы. С точки зрения синтаксиса, да и по смыслу, мы имеем цельное словосочетание. В предложении это единый член, мы его не делим на части. А морфология – это другое дело, там надо для каждого слова определить принадлежность к определенной части речи. И тогда это действительно порядковое числительное, что следует из определения дроби  как с л о в о с о ч е т а н и я количественного и порядкового числительных.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, конечно, имеется в виду дробное количественное числительное. Потому что "одна пятая часть". Порядковым оно было бы, если бы под *пятой частью* имелось в виду, что часть не третья, не шестая и не седьмая из, к примеру, восьми, а именно пятая из восьми.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Меня смущает определение в учебнике 6 класса, что дробное числительное всегда составное (кроме полтора и полтораста), то есть состоит из как минимум двух частей: количественного числительного (одна) и порядкового (пятая). Здесь в предложении нет слова "одна", есть только "пятая".

Comment: Если "пятая (часть)" - дробное, то получается, что нужно внимательно смотреть на контекст, в котором употреблено числительное, чтобы отличить дробное от порядкового?

Comment: @Оксана62 'одна' здесь подразумевается. В русском языке нередко слова, которые и так ясны и/или восстанавливаются из контекста, не пишутся и не произносятся. Это называется эллипсисом. Так что вы правы: в таких случаях надо не упускать из виду контекст.